# Compare items in 2 lists using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I want to compare some items in 2 Lists:

Update item "Company Name" in List 2 when it not match with item "Existing Company" in List 1.

I don't know how to proceed!

Comment: How do you match two items? Do they have the same name?

Comment: I have a workflow that copy the value from the item in List 1 in item of List 2. Now I want to Update this items.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear how You decide (based on what properties) which items from "List 2" needs to be updated.

But in general it seems that You could use this script - please adjust based on Your system values (webs URL, list names, field internal names etc).

```
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell }

$web = Get-SPWeb "https://www.contoso.com"

$list1 = $web.Lists["List Name 1"]
$list2 = $web.Lists["List Name 2"]

foreach($item1 in $list1.Items)
{
    $searchValue = $item1["Title"]

    $query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
    $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
    $query.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>" + $searchValue + "</Value></Contains></Where>"
    $query.RowLimit = 10    
    # leave value 10 to catch if multiple items are found OR change to 1 and remove "if-else-else" if you are sure for unique matching

    $items2 = $list2.GetItems($query)

    if($items2.Count -eq 1)
    {   
        # if values are unique, item collection "$items2" should contain only one item 
        $item2 = $items2[0]

        $item2["Field 1"] = $item1["Other Field"]
        $item2["Field 2"] = "lorem ipsum"

        $item2.Update()
    } 
    else if ($items2.Count -eq 0)   
    {
        Write-host "# No matching items found for value:" + $searchValue 
    } 
    else 
    {
        Write-host "# Multiple matching items found for value:" + $searchValue 
    }
}

$web.Dispose();
Write-Host "End" -b DarkGreen -f Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a second workflow in your source list, which is triggered when an item changes and then update the item in the destination list?

To identify the correct item in the destination list, I would recommend to store the item ID of the source list in a column in the destination list, when you initially copy the item from the source to the destination.